# Union with pointers

Tags: c++, unions

I have an union with 2 pointers to different data types:

```
union{
    UCHAR *_rawData;
    RGB *_RGBData;
};
typedef struct RGB
{
    UCHAR red;
    UCHAR green;
    UCHAR blue;
}RGB;
```

later in code...

```
_rawData = new UHCAR[126];
_RGBData = new _RGBData[42]; //3 times lower than rawData
```

So my question is.. Is it safe to make union like this? Theoretically both variables use 126 bytes so it should be ok but I'm not sure so I asked here

Comment: It is rare to see anything other than a "discriminated" union in practice. That basically means that you have a way to determine which type in the union is the one that's "active". You must be careful to always maintain that invariant. The most typical implementation is to use an enum.

Comment: Depending on what you wish to accomplish, it might be better to use `union { UCHAR raw[3]; RGB rgb };`.  The `raw` is used for code that is unaware of pixel formatting and the `rgb` is used for code that is aware.  You should verify that the sizes are the same with `static_assert()` or some mechanism; it is possible that the compiler would pad RGB, which would require packed structures.  There would only be one `new` needed, which is significant for larger image formats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The union by itself is valid, but only one member of the union can be active at any time:

- Doing the two initialisation as later in the code is hence definitively wrong:  the first pointer will be lost.
- You have to fin a way to determine which of the member is active.

Comment: Will it be wrong if I create it via the first pointer and delete via the second one?

Comment: As only one member can be active, you can only delete once.  If you use/delete the wrong member, the result is undefined.  In your case, as you have pointer to POD data structures and no specific destructor is defined, it could work, but it's very unsafe.